# Does group.offset not taken care of while doing group.format and group.main in solr group search?

Tags: solr, lucene

I have indexed document with `document_type_id`(possible values 1,2,3,4) field.

I want to do pagination in `solr`, so that my first page results in say 2 document from each doc type.

So I have done grouping in document field like this

```
fq=document_type_id:(1 2 3 4)&group=true&group.field=document_type_id&group.limit=2&group.offset=0
```

This results me 8 docs in 4 different groups. Which is cool, now if I want this to be in a single list I do

```
fq=document_type_id:(1 2 3 4)&group=true&group.field=document_type_id&group.limit=2&group.offset=0&group.format=simple
```

This also works well.

Now for my second page if I set `group.offset=2` the grouped results are fine but when I do `group.format=simple` the results are again same as it  were for first page.

i.e No matter what the value of `group.offset` is, return is always same if you apply `group.format=simple` OR `group.main=true`

Comment: Solr version i am using is 4.7

Comment: I have ran into same problem and I have yet to find the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe it is not possible :(

[Github Solr Source](https://github.com/apache/lucene-solr/blob/master/solr/core/src/java/org/apache/solr/search/grouping/distributed/requestfactory/TopGroupsShardRequestFactory.java#L93)

```
//From TopGroupsShardRequestFactory class in Solr

// If group.format=simple group.offset doesn't make sense
    Grouping.Format responseFormat = rb.getGroupingSpec().getResponseFormat();
    if (responseFormat == Grouping.Format.simple || rb.getGroupingSpec().isMain()) {
      sreq.params.remove(GroupParams.GROUP_OFFSET);
    }
```